# Can't find reason for CORS error with Express API

Tags: node.js, cors

I have a static website that I'm adding a simple hit tracker to. This is from the site's JS:

```
function addHit() {
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
  };
  fetch("https://myapi.com/hit", options);
}

window.onload = addHit;
```

This request comes to an Express server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://www.mywebsite.com",
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // code rendering hits so I can see them...
});

app.post("/hit", (req, res) => {
  // code updating hits in database
  // returns res.status(200) on success
  // returns res.status(400) on failure
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 8000;
}
const listener = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

When I open my webpage, the hit count is updated as expected. But after 30 seconds, I get two errors in the console.

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myapi.com/hit. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

"TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be added by the `cors` package, and if the request really was blocked, the hit count shouldn't be updated.

Any input on what could possibly be causing this would be much appreciated. If any more code is necessary, I'll be happy to add it, but removing the one posted snippet of the static site clears all errors.

Comment: Have you tried with http? Not https? May be your issue is with https

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but still the same errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, it turns out the problem had nothing at all to do with CORS. There was a misplaced return statement in the api route causing the request to timeout. Very strange that the error in the console was about CORS, but so it goes...

Answer (score 0):

From your code
What this does is restrict the origin access passed

```
  app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://www.mywebsite.com",
  })
);
```

> Instead what you want to do is

```
    app.use(cors(credentials: true));
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
    res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
     "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-        Type, Accept"
  );

     let allowedOrigins = [
    "http://your app.com", ..add more ];
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

     if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.sendStatus(200);
     } else {
      next();
     }
     });
```

Although If you are using the CORS library you can simply 
Us this code snippet the package handles the rest

app.use(cors());

Comment: I tried that snippet as well, (even though it allows unrestricted access from any website,) and the error is still the same.

Comment: Check out my edited answer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but after trying it, the errors are still the same.

Comment: Okay Glad to help

Comment: Check out https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/README.md#configuring-cors-asynchronously. 

You can also share if this helps or you figure it out